# Direct string representation in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a simple way to get the direct string representation of a Ruby construct?

For example:

```
a = [:foo, :bar]
```

When calling `a.to_s` I get:

```
"foobar"
```

What I am looking for is:

```
"[:foo, :bar]"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Ruby are you using?  Using Ruby 1.9 I get:

```
irb(main):002:0> a = [:foo, :bar]
=> [:foo, :bar]
irb(main):003:0> a.to_s
=> "[:foo, :bar]"
irb(main):004:0> a.inspect
=> "[:foo, :bar]"
```

**Edit:** As @fl00r has pointed out, in 1.8.7 you can use `inspect`.  In general, `inspect` is supposed to provide human-readable strings even when `to_s` does not.  From the [ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001025):

> obj.inspect → string
>
> Returns a string containing a human-readable representation of obj. If not overridden and no instance variables, uses the to_s method to generate the string.

[to_s](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001024) makes no claims about being human readable.

Comment: Funny how often one could use a method (`inspect`) and never realize what it really does :-/

Answer (score 2):

In 1.8.7 you can use `inspect` method for that

```
a = [:foo, :bar]
a_string = a.inspect
```

Answer (score 1):

For "simple" objects, `inspect` is what you are looking for.

```
>> [:a, :b].inspect
=> "[:a, :b]"
```

For more complex objects, it may not be all that helpful:

```
>> StringIO.new.inspect
=> "#<StringIO:0x00000100cc68d8>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `inspect` method, e.g.:

```
a = [:foo, :bar]
a.inspect # => "[:foo, :bar]"
```